# How can I use the form control in a drupal form?

Tags: 7, forms

In [Drupal forms API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7) there is a control type called ["form"](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#form) which, I think, allows nesting forms inside other forms. There is no usage example out there and the search term is a bit tricky so Google couldn't help. Would you please tell me how can I use this control in my forms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest forms . I think the `form` element type is the implicit type of the root element (ie. the array) build by a form builder. It is included in the Form API documentation to document its properties and for completeness.

If you need to group elements inside a form together, you can use a [fieldset](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#fieldset) or [container](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#container) element.

Answer (score 2):

Forms can not be nested in HTML. Since Drupal generates HTML, this should not be possible.

Comment: So why did they include this control type ?